# Programmatically Checkbox is not getting style

Tags: java, android

I am creating a `CheckBox` and a `RadioButton` programmatically, however in some devices the text is drawn over the option and they become black.
Please help me to resolve this

---

Code for Checkbox:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);  
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(context);  
cb.setId(opcao.getId());  
cb.setText(opcao.getValor());  
if (UtilSystem.isNotNull(selecionados) && selecionados.size()>0){

for (Integer cdSelected: selecionados){  
     if (cdSelected.equals(opcao.getId())){  
         cb.setChecked(true);  
     }  
 }}


  cb.setPadding(0,15,0,15); cb.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_transparent_grey));
```

---

Code for RadioButton

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rgChecklist);  

for (final ChecklistTemplatePerguntaOpcao opcao: opcoes){
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
            rb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rb.setId(opcao.getId());
            rb.setText(opcao.getValor());
if (UtilSystem.isNotNull(selected) && opcao.getId().equals(selected)){
                rb.setChecked(true);               
            }

            rb.setPadding(0,15,0,15);
     rb.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_transparent_grey));   

   rg.addView(rb);
}
```

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the XML file please?

Comment: Everything looks as it should be. Maybe you can share some other code because the problem is not here.